# springProfile is not read when loading logback-spring.xml through JoranConfigurator

Tags: java, spring-logback, logback-classic

If I load logback-spring.xml explictly using JoranConfigurator, it is not resolving log.path defined in  . I tried by passing `log.dir` as startup argument as `-Dlog.dir=/ff/test/log`

```
  JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
    configurator.setContext(context);
    configurator.doConfigure("logback-spring.xml")
```

But when log is initialized it shows as 
`${log.dir}` shows `log_dir_IS_UNDEFINED`.

`${log.dir}` is defined as below

```
 <springProfile name="dev">
        <property name="LOGS" value="${log.dir}" />
    </springProfile>
```

Is there anyway to specify profile if loading explicitly?

If log is initialized as part of spring boot run. It loads the profile and initialized properly. In my case, I want to initialize the log before spring boot run.